# app store submit process (BundleID)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, submit, bundle

Just a simple question about the submit process for AppSore using Xcode 4 (I know already asked, but didn't work for me).

I have my app ready for publish. I have all my certificates, and I can see my provisioning profile with an ID such as `xxxxxxx.com.blabla.App`.

If I set my  Xcode project identifier to `com.blabla.App` I can select my distribution certificate (it indicates "for Application Identifiers `com.blabla.App` ").

The project compiles but when I try to submit the App I get the following error

> The bundle ID com.blabla.App" defined in your Xcode Project does not match the Bundle ID you entered for this app in iTunes connect xxxxxx.com.blabla.App.

If I try to use this bundle (`xxxxxx.com.blabla.App`) in the Xcode project, then I cannot select the certificated, is for (`com.blabla.App`) apps.

I know the solution should be very simple, but, It's mu first time :).

thanks

Comment: check the bundle identifier in .plist file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying, that the Bundle ID in iTunes Connect and the one in your project settings are different from one another? If so, you should make them identical. My advise is to remove remove the app from iTunes connect and go trough the setup from start. When you do it, make sure you enter the same App ID as the one in Xcode.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok. I got it. Creating a new App using the old bundle ID instead of creating a new one. I think the problem was I wrote xxxxxx.com.blabla.App instead of com.blabla.App. 

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Just spent 12 hours resolving this so thought I would contribute my 2 cents:

1. The Bundle Identifier should be com.companyname.appname - this has to be the same as the Bundle ID when you create your app in iTunes Connect
2. Your Bundle Seed ID (App ID Prefix) ie. 10 digit code SHOULD NOT be entered into xcode nor the bundle ID when creating your app above. The only place you will see it is the App ID within PROVISIONING PORTAL > App IDs. This was very confusing - basically just enter the above (com.companyname.appname) for App ID SUFFIX

FYI the order from scratch should be:

1. Get Certificates for Developer and Distribution in Provisioning Portal > Certificates
2. Create APP IDs in Provisioning Portal > App ID
3. Create Provisioning profile for Dev and Distr in Provisioning Portal > Provisioning
4. Finally create the app in iTunes Connect

oh and in case you delete your app but lose your name:
http://hesh.am/2012/01/recovering-a-deleted-app-name-in-itunes-connect/

Answer (score 1):

just visit apple developer forum or try out some good blog lonk like [part 1](http://sugartin.info/2012/01/17/complete-apple-store-upload-process-using-xcode-4-2/) [part2](http://sugartin.info/2012/01/19/complete-apple-store-upload-process-using-xcode-4-2-part-2/) or use ray wenderlich tutorial to submit app on [iTunes Store](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

See Apple's published steps to resolve this error [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2294/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011374-CH1-TNTAG5).
The older wording of this same error was:

> Bundle identifier: (x) differs from reserved bundle identifier: (y)